# c# add the footer only in current section

Tags: c#

I am using c# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;.

Here is the for loop I am using to go through every section of a document and adding a footer when I click on a button.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord;
            object oMissing = Type.Missing;
            oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            oWord = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            foreach (word.Section wordSection in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Sections)
            {
                        word.HeaderFooter hf = wordSection.Footers[word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
                        hf.LinkToPrevious = false;
                        hf.Range.Font.Size = 7;
                        hf.Range.Font.ColorIndex = word.WdColorIndex.wdBlack;
                        hf.Range.Text = "Inserting Footer Text in current section of a document";
            }
        }
```

Now I would like to add the footer only in current section and not in any other section.

So for example, I have a document with section 1,2,3,4,5 and if I am currently at section 3 and click on that button, I want to add a footernote only for pages under section 3.

Comment: So,  is the problem that your loop is going through each section, and you want to know what section you're in so you can add the footer there?

Comment: The index of wordSection  tells me which section I am in. But how do I check if that section is the current/active section of the document. For example, I am in page 12 of a 100 page document. And page 12 is under section 3. When I was at page 12, I click on the button and I want to add footer for all pages for section 3. But I dont see any property for wordSection  to know if this the active section.

Comment: Right now the loop is adding footer in every section.

Comment: I can't currently use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application, if there is no property to get the current section, have you looked to see if there is some sort of special character or hidden section beginning/ending that you can't check for before adding the footer.

Answer (score 1):

Got Respond from Microsoft blog:

For adding footernote only for pages under current section, you need first go to next section and set LinkToPrevious as false and then back to current section for setting footernote.

Here is the simply code.

```
        Word._Application oWord;
        object oMissing = Type.Missing;
        oWord = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        int sectionIndex = oWord.Selection.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndSectionNumber];
        Word.Section wordSection;
        Word.HeaderFooter hf;

        if (sectionIndex != oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) { 
        wordSection = oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections[sectionIndex+1];
        hf = wordSection.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
        hf.LinkToPrevious = false;
        }

        wordSection = oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections[sectionIndex];
        hf = wordSection.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
        hf.LinkToPrevious = false;
        hf.Range.Font.Size = 7;
        hf.Range.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlack;
        hf.Range.Text = "Inserting Footer Text in current section of a document";
```